# Why can Google Cloud Build triggers not subscribed to Pub/Sub "cloud-builds" topic anymore?

Tags: google-cloud-build

Using Google Cloud Build offers to configure build triggers listening to pub/sub topics. A Google managed special topic "cloud-builds" can be created in Pub/Sub for subscription. Creating a cloud build trigger listening to the "cloud-builds" topic is suddenly failing (worked like a charm before):

```
Failed to create trigger: trigger should not listen on cloud-builds topic
```

This happens when the following command is issued:

```
gcloud alpha builds triggers create pubsub \
       --project=$PROJECT \
       --name=$TRIGGERNAME \
       --repo="$REPO" \
       --branch="main" \
       --topic=projects/$PROJECT/topics/cloud-builds \
       --build-config=cloudbuild.yaml`
```

This happens also when trying to create the trigger on the Cloud Build Console or via REST API.

The command succeeds if another topic is used like the Google managed "gcr" topic for Artifact Repository event.

**Edit:**

Meanwhile I got around this issue by writing a Cloud Function which repeats/proxies all events of the "cloud-builds" topic to another custom topic which can be subscribed to by a google cloud build trigger. This works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same situation as you and contacted Google Cloud Support.
They said the reason of this situation is that they have restricted Cloud Build to subscribe `cloud-builds` Pub/Sub topic to fix a certain bug. They also mentioned it's not sure that this change will be reverted and recommended a workaround to copy messages in `cloud-builds` topic to another topic and subscribe the another topic.

I deployed these files to Google Cloud Functions to copy

index.js

```js
const { PubSub } = require('@google-cloud/pubsub')

exports.replicate = (event, _context) => {
  const client = new PubSub()
  const json = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(event.data, 'base64').toString())
  client.topic('cloud-build-results').publishMessage({ json })
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "cloud-builds-result-replicator",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

cloudbuild.yaml

```yaml
steps:
  - id: 'Deploy to Cloud Functions'
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        gcloud functions deploy cloud-builds-result-replicator \
          --entry-point=replicate \
          --runtime=nodejs18 \
          --trigger-topic=cloud-builds \
          --allow-unauthenticated \
          --project=$PROJECT_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I did exact the same workaround but using python. Would be great if Google would announce such a breaking change to Cloud Build users.